# Can't understand the proof that any subgroup of index 2 is normal (invariant)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-explanation, normal-subgroups

I am tasked with the following problem:

> Prove that any subgroup of index 2 is normal (invariant)

This is the proof that I have been given:

> Let’s say that group $G = \{E, g_2, . . . g_{|G|}\}$ has a subgroup $H = \{E, g_2, g_3, . . . , g_{|G|/2}\}$ of index 2. $H$ has half as many elements as $G$ has. Since the distinct cosets of $H$ do not share any elements, and each coset has $|H|$ elements, we can conclude that there exists only $|G|/|H| = 2$ distinct left cosets, and for same reasons, only 2 distinct right cosets of $H$. Now that we know $H$ only has two distinct right and left cosets, $\color{red}{\text{we must show that the left cosets are the same as the right cosets}}$.
>
> The subgroup itself is always a coset as we can multiply the identity with the subgroup. That is, the left and right cosets $HE = EH = H$. Since the cosets do not share any elements, the other left and right coset is the set containing all elements of $G$ not in $H$, let’s call it $H' = \{g_{|G|/2+1}, . . . , g_{|G|−1}, g_{|G|}\}$. Therefore the two left cosets are $H$ and $H'$, and the two right cosets are also $H$ and $H'$. The left and right cosets of $H$ are the same, and so $H$ is an invariant subgroup.
>
> More generally, for $h \in H$, $hH = Hh = H$ and for $g' \in H'$, $g'H = Hg' = H'$ . So in any case, $gH = Hg$ for any $g$ and the subgroup is invariant.

End of proof.

---

I'm okay right up until the point I marked in red. Why do we need to show that the left cosets and right cosets are the same?

---

#### Remark:

I don't see this as a 'homework style' question since I am asking for an explanation on a particular proof, and there is a tag for that. But, if you see fit to retag it with homework-and-exercises then fine by me.

Comment: It can be shown that a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ is normal if and only if every left coset is a right coset. [proof in most any abstract algebra book]

Comment: @coffeemath Thanks for that, I have books from Hammermesh and Petrashen, but I only care about understanding *this* proof, (the one above in my question).

Comment: I thought you only wanted to understand the statement in red. That's what you said anyway...

Comment: @coffeemath Okay, I see what you mean, I want to understand the whole of the proof, not just the part in red, I ought to have said that in my post really, but I've said it now :-)

Comment: Why the downvote without even a comment to suggest improvement to the quesion?

Comment: BLAZE-- It wasn't me who downvoted. (Not saying your last comment was made for me, just informing you about my not being the downvote.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The left cosets of $G$ with respect to $H$ are the subsets of $G$ of the form $gH$, with $g\in G$, whereas the right cosets are those of the from $Hg$. Now, suppose that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. This means that, for each $g\in G$, $g^{-1}Hg\subset H$. Actually, since $G$ is finite, it means that $g^{-1}Hg=H$. This, in turn, is equivalent to $Hg=gH$. So, if $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, $\{Hg\mid g\in G\}=\{gH\mid g\in G\}$; in other words, the set of right cosets is equal to the set of left cosets. It's not hard to prove that if the set of right cosets is equal to the set of left cosets, then $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: In the first line you write "The left cosets of $G/H$ .....". Does $G/H$ mean $G$ or $H$ or are you writing set-difference?

Comment: I have edited that first sentence. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, this is clear now thanks.

Comment: "Now, suppose that $H$ is a normal subgroup of  $G$", this quesion asks you to prove that $H$ *is* normal. Your proof assumes it. Can you prove it without making that assumption?

Comment: What I did was to prove that, given a subgroup $H$ of $G$, $H$ is a normal subgroup if and only if the set of left cosets is equal to the set of right cosets.

Comment: Your answer is very helpful for me, (I upvoted it), but the way I interpret this is that you did 'suppose that $H$ is normal', on a strict proof you are not allowed to use what you are trying to prove. This proof of yours seems to work the other way round, and could be improved by first proving the left and right cosets are equal and then proving that because of the equal coset condition that $H$ is  normal. I don't want to sound ungrateful for your answer, and I'm sorry if I am not interpreting your proof correctly. This proof seems to use something that should be proved.

Comment: BLAZE-- Jose mentions the direction you asked in your above comment as the last thing in his answer, saying at that point "It's not hard to show" meaning he didn't put that proof in his answer but it's an easy proof. In my comment I was saying that proof will be found in any good abstract algebra book.

Comment: As I wrote in my previous comment, what I did was to prove that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ if and only if the set of left cosets is equal to the set of right cosets. I stated that result, and then I proved that **if** $H$ is normal, **then** the set of left cosets is equal to the set of right cosets. At the end, I wrote that it is easy to prove that **if** the set of left cosets is equal to the set of right cosets, **then** $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.