# What does "contain full conjugacy classes" mean (in simple English please)?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, terminology, normal-subgroups

I'm trying to understand the solution to question part $(vi.)$ below:

[image: group table]

> A subgroup is invariant if $gHg^{−1} = H$ for any $g \in G$. This is equivalent to saying that
> a subgroup $H$ is invariant if it has the same right and left cosets, or $\color{red}{\text{the same as saying that it should contain full conjugacy classes}}$. This is true for $\{E\}$, $\{E, D, F \}$ and $G$ which contain full classes, but not for $\{E, A\}$, $\{E, B\}$ and $\{E, C\}$. Also since $\{E, D, F\}$ has index two $\big(\mid G\mid/\mid H\mid = 2 \big)$, from question 2 and my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4181935/cant-understand-the-proof-that-any-subgroup-of-index-2-is-normal-invariant) we know that this subgroup is invariant.
> As a check, let’s see if $\{E, A\}$ has the same left and right cosets:
>
> Left cosets of $\{E, A\} \,\text{are}\, A\{E, A\} = \{A, E\},\quad B\{E, A\} = \{B, F \},\quad C\{E, A\} = \{C, D\}$
>
> Right cosets of $\{E, A\}\,\text{are}\, \{E, A\}A = \{A, E\},\quad \{E, A\}B = \{B, D\},\quad \{E, A\}C = \{C, F\}$
>
> We see that the left cosets are not the same as the right cosets. Hence $\{E, A\}$ is not an invariant subgroup. The same thing holds for $\{E, B\}$ and $\{E, C\}$.
> Therefore only $\{E\}, \color{blue}{\{E, D, F \}}$ and $G$ are invariant subgroups.

I marked the part in red for which I don't understand. In part $iii.$ it was found that the conjugacy classes are $\{E\}$, $\{A,B,C\}$, $\{D,F\}$. So (from the quote above - the last part of the solution to $vii.$), $\color{blue}{\{E,D,F\}}$ 'contains full conjugacy classes', but what does this mean in simple English (where possible)?

Comment: It means that the subgroup is the union of a set of conjugacy classes of $G$. Or, in other words, if it contains one element of a conjugacy class, then it contains all elements of that class.

Comment: @DerekHolt Thanks for your reply, I'm still very confused however, but $\{E,D,F\}$ does not contain elements $\{A,B,C\}$. So how is this $\{E,D,F\}$  a 'full' conjugacy class? Sorry, to sound stupid but it's really hard teaching yourself this stuff.

Comment: Consider $G = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ the group of integers mod $6$. Then, as an abelian group, for any $g$ and $h$, $ghg^{-1} = h$. Hence, the conjugacy class of the integer $h$ is $\{h\}$. It follows that $\{3,4,5\}$ contains the full conjugacy class of all its elements, even if there is no element of $\{0,1,2\}$ in it. (This is a comment on your comment saying $\{E,D,F\}$ contains no element of $\{A,B,C\}$.)

Comment: The word "full" emphasizes that if any part of a conjugacy class is used, then the whole conjugacy class is used. It is ok if a conjugacy class is not used at all, but it is bad if a conjugacy class is used partially. So {E}, {D,F}, {E,D,F}, {E,A,B,C} and {A,B,C,D,F} are all made up of full conjugacy classes, while {D,A} is not (it has D but not F, and it has A but not B,C).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To see that $\{E,D,F\}$ is a union of whole conjugacy classes, here is the (tedious) work that you must carry out:

1. The conjugacy class of $E$, namely the set $\{AEA^{-1},BEB^{-1},CEC^{-1},DED^{-1},EEE^{-1},FEF^{-1}\}$, is equal to $\{E\}$ (verify by tedious calculation, or more easily by noticing that $E$ is the identity element of the group).
2. The conjugacy class of $D$, namely the set $\{ADA^{-1}, BDB^{-1}, CDC^{-1}, DDD^{-1}, EDE^{-1}, FDF^{-1}\}$, is equal to $\{D,F\}$ (verify by tedious calculation).
3. The conjugacy class of $F$ is also equal to $\{D,F\}$ (verify using the theorem that the conjugacy classes of any group are a partition of that group, and the fact that $\{D,F\}$ is a conjugacy class which you have already verified and which contains $F$).

Therefore, the set $\{E,D,F\}$ is a union of two whole conjugacy classes, namely
$$\{E,D,F\} = \{E\} \cup \{D,F\}
$$
Notice, there is another whole conjugacy classes that is not in this union. So, to say that a subset $X$ of the group is "a union of whole conjugacy classes" means, more precisely, "there exists a subset of the set of all conjugacy classes whose union is $X$".

Or, to put it another way, "$X$ is the union of the conjugacy classes of the elements of $X$". Notice: *no element of* the conjugacy class $\{A,B,C\}$ is contained in the set $X = \{E,D,F\}$. But that does not contradict the meaning of $X$ being a union of whole conjugacy classes: $X$ is not the union of *every* whole conjugacy class, but it is a union of *some of* the conjugacy classes.