# Unitary operators, inner products and unit operators with Dirac notation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, inner-products, adjoint-operators, unitary-matrices

From my notes, I have that for a unitary matrix:

$$\underline{\underline{U}}^\dagger=\underline{\underline{U}}^{-1},\qquad \underline{\underline{U}}^\dagger=\big(\underline{\underline{U}}^{T}\big)^*$$
and for unitary matrix, $\underline{\underline A}$, the scalar product is such that
$$\Big(\underline x, \,{\underline{\underline{A}}\cdot{\underline y}}\Big)=\Big({\underline{\underline{A}}^\dagger\cdot\underline x, \,{\underline y}}\Big)\tag{1}$$

then $$\Big({\underline{\underline{U}}\cdot\underline x, \,{\underline{\underline{U}}}\cdot{\underline y}}\Big)=\Big({\underline{\underline{U}}^{\dagger}\cdot{\underline{\underline{U}}}\cdot\underline x,\,{\underline y}}\Big)=(\underline x,\, \underline y)\tag{2}$$

---

### *Aside*

In the notation I'm using, I denote a vector with an underline and a matrix with a double-underline, but in $(1)$ and $(2)$ I didn't want to put the dot between vectors and matrices, but without the dot the underlines merge together which looks bad, sorry about this.

---

My first problem is that I do not understand the logic behind equation $(1)$ (and hence $(2)$ also). As I mentioned in the first comment to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4245538/how-to-construct-the-c-4v-character-table-given-its-cayley-table) - I only have access to some incomplete (written) lecture notes where $(1)$ was given *without* proof, I tried to find proof of this property, but am so far unsuccessful.

Instead of leaving the question at that, I'm going to put this question into context by asking 2 more related questions that utilize this property:

1. Proof of linear independence of degeneracy for $C_3$ symmetry group:

Suppose we have a group $$G: C_3, C_3^2=C_3^{-1}, C_3^3=E$$
With character table
$$
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
 C_{3} & E
& C_3 & C_3^2=C_3^{-1}  \\\hline
 \chi^{(1)} & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
 \chi^{(2)} & 1  & e^{i 2\pi/3} & e^{-i 2\pi/3}\\\hline
 \chi^{(3)} & 1  & e^{-i 2\pi/3} & e^{i 2\pi/3}\\\hline
\end{array}
$$

Character table displays no degeneracy as IRREPs, $\chi$ are 1D. But,
there *is* actually a 2-fold degeneracy as $$\hat H \psi_n=E_n \psi_n$$
& $$\hat H \psi_n^*=E_n \psi_n^*$$ so $\psi_n$ and $\psi_n^*$ both have energy $E_n$. So if $\psi_n$, $\psi_n^*$ belong to $\chi$, $\chi^*$ then they are **linearly independent**. $\psi_n$ is the basis for $\chi$ and $\psi_n^*$ is the basis for $\chi^*$.

To show linear independence take inner product:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid blue]{\psi_n \in \big(1,\, e^{+i\phi},\, e^{-i\phi}\big)\\
{\psi_n}^* \in \big(1,\, e^{-i\phi},\, e^{+i\phi}\big)}\tag{X}$$
where $\phi=2\pi/3$

$$\hat T_{C_3}\psi_n=e^{+i\phi}\psi_n$$
$$\hat T_{C_3}{\psi_n}^*=e^{-i\phi}{\psi_n}^*$$
Where $\hat T_{C_3}$ is a coordinate transformation operator corresponding to a $C_3$ rotation.

So inner product is $\langle \psi_n |{\psi_n}^*\rangle=\langle \psi_n |\hat T_{C_3}^{-1}\hat T_{C_3}|{\psi_n}^*\rangle$, where $\bbox[yellow,5px]{\hat T_{C_3} \hat T_{C_3}^{-1}=\hat 1}$, where $\hat 1$ is the unit operator, since $\bbox[5px,border:2px solid green]{\hat T_g^{-1}=\hat T_g^\dagger}$ for group element $g$. So
$$\langle \psi_n |\hat T_{C_3}^{-1}\hat T_{C_3}|{\psi_n}^*\rangle\stackrel{\color{red}{?}}{=}\langle\hat T_{C_3}\psi_n | \hat T_{C_3}{\psi_n}^*\rangle =\langle e^{+i\phi}\psi_n |e^{-i\phi}{\psi_n}^*\rangle\stackrel{\color{blue}{?}}{=}{\big(e^{+i\phi}\big)}^*e^{-i\phi}\langle\psi_n|\psi_n^*\rangle\tag{3}$$$$\implies\langle\psi_n|\psi_n^*\rangle=e^{-2i\phi}\langle\psi_n|\psi_n^*\rangle\implies \langle\psi_n|\psi_n^*\rangle=0 \quad\blacksquare$$

For the red question mark, I have no idea how that equality follows. With regards to the blue question mark, I'm not sure, but, I think this may be a property of the Dirac notation; whereby the Bras are complex row vectors such that, $\langle A |=\big(a_1^*,a_2^*,a_3^*,\cdots\big)$, so to take the exponential outside requires taking the complex conjugate of the exponential. Can someone please confirm whether this logic is correct and explain to me how the red equality follows?

2. Part of the derivation of the matrix element in selection rules.

For matrix element $$O_{\alpha\, i\, j}=\langle \psi_i |\hat O_\alpha|\phi_j\rangle=\langle\psi_i|\color{red}{\hat T_g^{-1}}\hat T_g \hat O_\alpha \hat T_g^{-1}\hat T_g | \phi_j\rangle\stackrel{?}{=}\langle\hat T_g \psi_i | \hat T_g \hat O_\alpha \hat T_g^{-1}|\hat T_g \phi_j\rangle\tag{4}$$

In the above, I think the author is inserting the unit operator twice, used earlier in the green box, (where it was used for a particular group element, $C_3$ - highlighted yellow). In the last equality with a question mark above it, I can see that the author has distributed the $\hat T_g$ into the Ket (which by my understanding are just column vectors with no complex numbers). But how did the $\hat T_g^{-1}$ (marked red) end up operating on the far left of the Bra?

---

### Update:

I have been given a nice swift proof of equation $(1)$; $(x,Ay) = x^\dagger Ay = (A^\dagger x)^\dagger y = (A^\dagger x, y)$ with thanks to @BenGrossmann. I understand this simple proof and I had hoped it would allow me to understand instances 1. and 2. But there is a problem.

Am I to interpret inner product, $(x,Ay)$ as $\langle x|A y\rangle$ in the Dirac notation?

The problem is that in $(3)$ and $(4)$ we are not computing an inner product, but instead a matrix element, which by my understanding is written generally as $$\langle \phi |\hat Q|\psi \rangle\equiv \int\phi^*(x)\hat Q\psi(x)dx$$ and this can be seen on [page 1 of this](http://www.hep.manchester.ac.uk/u/stevew/teaching/dirac.pdf)

In the case of $(3)$ the unit operator is being used, $$\langle \psi_n |\hat 1|{\psi_n}^*\rangle\langle \psi_n |\hat T_{C_3}^{-1}\hat T_{C_3}|{\psi_n}^*\rangle\stackrel{\color{red}{?}}{=}\langle\hat T_{C_3}\psi_n | \hat T_{C_3}{\psi_n}^*\rangle$$

Whereas in the case of $(4)$
$$O_{\alpha\, i\, j}=\langle \psi_i |\hat O_\alpha|\phi_j\rangle=\langle\psi_i|\hat 1 \hat O_\alpha \hat 1| \phi_j\rangle=\langle\psi_i|\color{red}{\hat T_g^{-1}}\hat T_g \hat O_\alpha \hat T_g^{-1}\hat T_g | \phi_j\rangle\stackrel{?}{=}\langle\hat T_g \psi_i | \hat T_g \hat O_\alpha \hat T_g^{-1}|\hat T_g \phi_j\rangle
$$

Since neither $(3)$ or $(4)$ are inner products I cannot utilize the now proven $(1)$. So could someone please explain how the equalities (with question marks above them) follow?

Comment: If $\dagger$ denotes the conjugate-transpose and $(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the usual "dot-product" over $\Bbb C^n$, then for any matrix $A$, we have $(Ax,y) = (x,A^\dagger y)$. Are you comfortable with this fact, or is this something that you want a proof/reference for?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Hi, I'm not comfortable with this fact and it is definitely something I want proof for, thanks.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that there is a post elsewhere on this site proving it, but I wasn't able to find it. In any case, one proof is as follows. Note that for any matrix product $AB$, we have $(AB)^\dagger = B^\dagger A^\dagger$. Moreover, for column-vectors $x,y$, we have $(x,y) = x^\dagger y$. Thus, 
$$
(x,Ay) = x^\dagger Ay = (A^\dagger x)^\dagger y = (A^\dagger x, y).
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks for your proof. Can this also be done for 2-row vectors? I ask because I just didn't see anything special about 2 column vectors.

Comment: With regard to your question in your update, the Dirac notation can be used either for the case where $\psi$ and $\phi$ are finite-dimensional vectors, or for the case when they are square- integrable functions (as in your formula with the integral). Both of these are cases of so-called "Inner Product Spaces", so the formalism is identical. In your examples (1) and (2) it is very unclear whether $\psi_n$ are meant to be functions (in which case the integral formula would be appropriate) or finite-dimensional vectors (in which case it would not be).

Comment: @MikeHawk Okay, thanks for explaining, I'm starting to understand now I think. It is just the term "Matrix Element" which confused me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bra-ket notation "in the abstract" represents a Hermitian inner product on the Hilbert space of states, where by definition linearity holds in second argument  and swapping the arguments conjugates the result: $\langle  \phi | (z+w) \psi  \rangle=z\langle \phi | \psi  \rangle+w\langle \phi | \psi  \rangle$ and $\langle \phi | \psi  \rangle=\overline{\langle \psi | \phi  \rangle}$. This implies $\langle (z+w) \phi |  \psi  \rangle=\overline{z+w}\langle \phi | \psi  \rangle$, so the product is conjugate-linear in the first argument.   (Note that this is a matter of convention; mathematicians often choose the Hermitian inner product to be linear in the first entry and conjugate-linear in the second one. This does not affect things in any substantial way, but I think both your sources use the "linear in second entry" convention, so we'll stick to that).

This explains the blue question mark in (3).

In the case when $\psi$ and $\phi$ are column vectors in some $\mathbb{C}^n$, the "usual" or "standard" inner product  given by  $\langle \phi | \psi  \rangle= \sum_{j=1}^n \overline{\phi_j}\psi_j$ (where each of the components $\phi_j$ and $\psi_j$ is a complex number). This has the properties above, that is, it's an example of  a Hermitian inner product (making $\mathbb{C}^n$ into a Hilbert space). It can also be written in matrix notation as $\langle \phi | \psi  \rangle=\bar{\phi}^T\psi=\psi^T\overline{\phi}$.

Suppose now that $A$ is a (bounded, linear) operator on our Hilbert space then its Hermitian conjugate  $A^\dagger$ is DEFINED by $\langle \phi, A \psi \rangle=\langle A^\dagger \phi,  \psi \rangle$ (this is uniquely defined since knowing product of $A^\dagger \phi$ with all vectors specifies $A^\dagger \phi$ uniquely, and one can check that the resulting map $A^\dagger$ is linear and bounded). Thus your equation (1) is a definition of $A^\dagger$.

We have $(XY)^\dagger=Y^\dagger X^\dagger$. Indeed, from definitions $\langle (XY)^\dagger u, v\rangle=\langle u, XYv \rangle=\langle X^\dagger u, Yv \rangle=\langle Y^\dagger X^\dagger u, Yv \rangle$ for all $u,v$, so $(XY)^\dagger=Y^\dagger X^\dagger$. This extends to  products of more than one operators, so that, for example, $(ABCD)^\dagger=D^\dagger C^\dagger B^\dagger A^\dagger$.

If the Hilbert space is $\mathbb{C}^n$, then dagger becomes "conjugate transpose" operation, since it is easy to check that in that case  $\langle \phi, A \psi \rangle=\overline{\phi}^T A\psi=(A^T\overline{\phi})^T\psi=\langle \overline{A}^T \phi, \psi\rangle$.

The  bra-ket notation is then extended to be $\langle \phi |  A|\psi\rangle=\langle \phi |  A\psi\rangle$  by definition. We have from above that this equals $\langle A^\dagger \phi | \psi\rangle$.

Unitary matrices can be defined EITHER as ones with $\langle U\phi| U\psi\rangle=\langle \phi| \psi \rangle$ OR as ones for which $U^\dagger=U^{-1}$. It is immediate from definition of $\dagger$ that these are equivalent.

Now all the operations in your question marks are explained:
Suppose we have an expression like  $\langle\phi |ABCD|\psi\rangle$. By definition this is $\langle\phi |ABCD\psi\rangle$. This is also equal to $\langle\phi|ABC |D\psi\rangle$ or $\langle\phi|AB |CD\psi\rangle$ etc. This means that we can move the righttmost operator  inbetween-bars to the right.  It is also, as we noted above, by the definition adjoint, equal to $\langle (ABCD)^\dagger \phi |\psi\rangle$. As established before, this is the same as $\langle D^\dagger C^\dagger B^\dagger A^\dagger \phi |\psi\rangle$. and the same as  $\langle (BCD)^\dagger A^\dagger \phi |\psi\rangle=\langle A^\dagger  \phi |(BCD)\psi\rangle=\langle A^\dagger  \phi|BCD |\psi\rangle$. This means that we can move the lefttmost operator inbetween-bars to the left with a dagger.

If the operator is unitary, then the dagger becomes inverse.

---

As a final note, when $\psi$ and $\phi$ are not finite-dimensional, but, instead lie in the space of complex-valued $L^2$ functions (on some space $X$) then the Hermitian product is the L^2 inner product $\langle \phi| \psi \rangle=\int_X \overline{\phi(x)}\psi(x) dx$ and our extended definition becomes $\langle \phi|A|\psi\rangle=\int_X \overline{\phi(x)}A(\psi(x)) dx$ agreeing with the formula in your post.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, I think I understand your answer. Just one question for you: For the 1st question in my post for the part I marked $(X)$ (in the blue boxes), suppose I took  $\psi_n,\, {\psi_n}^*=1$ then $\hat T_{C_3}\psi_n=1\cdot\psi_n$ and $\hat T_{C_3}\psi_n=1\cdot{\psi_n}^*$ then $\langle \psi_n |{\psi_n}^*\rangle=\langle \psi_n |\hat T_{C_3}^{-1}\hat T_{C_3}|{\psi_n}^*\rangle=\langle\hat T_{C_3}\psi_n | \hat T_{C_3}{\psi_n}^*\rangle = 1 \cdot 1 \cdot \langle \psi_n |{\psi_n}^*\rangle=\langle \psi_n |{\psi_n}^*\rangle$, but how does this show orthogonality?

Comment: You don't quite understand your comment (maybe some formatting issue?). The point is that you have two vectors, $\psi$ and $\psi^*$. While they may have the same eigenvalue for $H$ (same energy), have different eigenvalues for some unitary $T$, say one has $T \psi=e^{i \phi}\psi$ and another $T \psi^*=e^{-i \phi}\psi^*$. Then we compute the Hermitian product $\langle T \psi | T \psi^*\rangle$  in two ways.

Comment: On one hand it should be just equal to $\langle \psi | \psi^* \rangle$.  But on the other hand it is $\langle \psi | \psi^* \rangle = (e^{-i \phi})^* e^{i \phi} \langle \psi | \psi^* \rangle$, so the Hermitian product gets multiplied by $(e^{-i \phi})^* e^{i \phi}=e^{2i \phi} \neq 1$. The only way a number is equal to a non-unit multiple of itself is if it is zero, which is what we wanted to get.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you took two vectors that transformed the same way under $T$, then this argument would not o through - as we would expect, since for all we know these may actually have been the same vector, so the Hermitian product would not be zero.

Comment: I was just confused as to why the author *specifically* chose $e^{i \phi}$  from the basis $\psi_n \in (1,\, e^{+i\phi},\, e^{-i\phi})$ and $e^{-i \phi}$ from ${\psi_n}^* \in (1,\, e^{-i\phi},\, e^{+i\phi})$ instead of say $1$ (from both basis, ${\psi_n}$ and ${\psi_n}^*$). Is $1$ not a valid basis element to show orthogonality or am I still not understanding this correctly?

Comment: I see. The $e^{i\phi}$ is not obtained this way, it is not some "chosen" component of the vector. Rather, if you apply  $T$ to $\psi=(1, e^{i\phi}, e^{-i\phi})$ then ($T$ being rotation)  you get $T\psi= (e^{i\phi}, e^{-i\phi}, 1)=e^{i\phi}(1, e^{-2i\phi},e^{-i\phi}) =e^{i\phi} \psi$. So $e^{i\phi}$ is the eigenvalue corresponding to the eigenvector $\psi$. Similar calculation for the other vector gives $T \psi^*=e^{-i\phi} \psi^*$. In general, the eigenvalue will have nothing to do with any components of the vector; its just a coincidence that here it coincides with one of them.

Comment: I think I understand now, when we apply the rotation transformation operation,  $\hat T_{C_3}$, to the vector,  $\psi_n$,  $(1,e^{i\phi}, e^{-i\phi})$
  then  $\hat T_{C_3}\psi_n=(e^{i\phi}, e^{-i\phi}, 1)$  and this (as I understand it), has rotated the position to which the elements in the basis are ordered, such that $\hat T_{C_3}$  rotates $(1,\, e^{+i\phi},\, e^{-i\phi})$ to $(e^{i\phi}, e^{-i\phi}, 1)$, (moving all elements to the left in a cyclic fashion). In your 4th equality I presume  $e^{-2i \phi}=e^{i \phi}$, as two counter clockwise rotations by $\phi$ is the same ....

Comment: .....as one clockwise rotation by $\phi$ , and hence $(1, e^{-2i\phi},e^{-i\phi})=(1, e^{i\phi},e^{-i\phi})$. Is this understanding I have correct?

Comment: Yes, since $e^{3i\phi}=1$ we have $e^{-2i\phi}=e^{i\phi}$.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer and congratulations on the bounty! If you'll forgive me I just have one small question regarding equation $(\mathrm{K})$ which I have marked in your answer, and added color to make clear which part of each equality I am referring to. I understand how the first 2 equalities follow for $(\mathrm{K})$. But for $\color{red}{\alpha}$, I don't follow your logic. Could you please elaborate exactly on what you did you show that  $\langle D^\dagger C^\dagger B^\dagger A^\dagger \phi |\psi\rangle=\langle A^\dagger \phi |BC|D \psi\rangle$ with possible intermediate steps?

Comment: See edit for an elaboration.