# Question regarding notation and meaning of 'representations' in representation theory?

Tags: group-theory, notation, representation-theory

I have from some written notes that

[image: Representation theory intro]

[image: Representation theory intro 2]

---

### Aside

Please note, I did not write these notes, they were given to me by a friend, so there are some parts of the notes I had to cover up - this is the reason for the white rectangular boxes.

---

So according to the second image of the notes.

> $\underline{\underline D}(g_i)$ are the set of $n\times n$ matrices that form a representation of the group $G$. The order of this representation is $n$. The basis of the representation $D$ is $\{\hat e\}$, for $i=1,2,3,\cdots, n$. The representation space is $\mathbb{C}^n$

Since the index runs from $1$ to $n$ and the group elements, $g_i$ also bear this index, typically $|G|=m$ (the order of the group). So by my understanding so far there should be $m$ matrices - one corresponding to each group element $g_i$.
For my first question, is the "$n\times n$ matrices" talking about the size (dimensions) of each matrix? Or put another way; is it saying *each* matrix has $n$ rows and $n$ columns?

---

Later on in the notes I was given a proof for the great orthogonality theorem:

[image: Great orthogonality theorem]

The representations in the above image are labeled with a superscript, $D^{(i)}$ and $D^{(j)}$, and furthermore, it states that there are $m$ of these such matrices, where $|G|=m$ and $n_i$ here is the order of the IRREP.

My main question is *why* we need a whole set of representations, $D^{(i)},D^{(j)},D^{(k)},D^{(l)},\cdots,D^{(z)}$ or in principle infinite number of representations?

By way of example, the point group $C_{4v}$ which I was asking about in an [earlier question regarding its character table](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4245538/how-to-construct-the-c-4v-character-table-given-its-cayley-table), which has an order of 8 and therefore 8 matrices:

$$C_4=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos 2\pi/4 & -\sin 2\pi/4 & 0 \\
\sin 2\pi/4 & \cos 2\pi/4 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$C_4^3=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos 3\pi/2 & -\sin 3\pi/2 & 0 \\
\sin 3\pi/2 & \cos 3\pi/2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$C_2=\begin{bmatrix}
\cos \pi & -\sin \pi & 0 \\
\sin \pi & \cos \pi & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\sigma_x=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\sigma_y=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\sigma_d=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\sigma_{d^\prime}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -1 & 0 \\
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

and
$$E=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

Since all these matrices form a representation (call it $D^{(1)}$) for the point group $C_{4v}$, is it really possible to find another set of matrices, say, $D^{(2)}$ that represents the same point group $C_{4v}$?

Essentially, I'm just asking for one basic example where you can have multiple representations for the *same* finite point group.

Comment: @Jackson Yes, I meant finite point groups, and I will fix those typos, thanks for pointing that out, I appreciate that.

Comment: It seems like you're asking completely different questions here. One is "do more representations exist" and, totally, yes! Another is "isn't one enough?" and the answer is, well, this is math. Having an object is never enough. Representation theorists study representations, and are interested in knowing how many there are and how they're related to each other, in addition to what they say about the group $C_{4v}$

Comment: @Jackson I just gave an example of one point group that is represented by a set of matrices, $D$, all I'm looking for here is an example of where a point group can have more than one representation. Just one example is all I ask. The reason why I have asked this question is because I have studied so many proofs like Schur's 2nd lemma that require inequivalent IRREPS, $D^{(i)}$ & $D^{(j)}$. All I want is to see an example showing a point group with more than one representation. You see, I come from a physics perspective: What is the point of all this math if I can't even see one example?

Comment: The group here is an example. It has 5 inequivalent irreducible representations ("irreps"), which can be combined in infinitely many ways to form countably many inequivalent finite dimensional representations. The one you have here is the direct sum of the trivial representation with a faithful two-dimensional representation (this one may be referred to as the defining representation), so it has 2 irreps already inside it. An easily described third representation is the sign representation, which sends all 4 "$\sigma$"-elements to the $1\times1$ matrix $[-1]$ and the other 4 elements to $[1]$